# Does Application cache refresh its timeout during postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have this piece of code in which I'm storing user data in application cache, so as to prevent multiple user login using the same credentials.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//validate your user here (Forms Auth or Database, for example)
// this could be a new "illegal" logon, so we need to check
// if these credentials are already in the Cache
string sKey=TextBox1.Text+TextBox2.Text;
string sUser=Convert.ToString(Cache[sKey]);
if (sUser==null || sUser==String.Empty){
// No Cache item, so sesion is either expired or user is new sign-on
// Set the cache item and Session hit-test for this user---
TimeSpan SessTimeOut=new TimeSpan(0,0,HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout,0,0);
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(sKey,sKey,null,DateTime.MaxValue,SessTimeOut,
   System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,null);
Session["user"]=TextBox1.Text+TextBox2.Text;
// Let them in - redirect to main page, etc.
Label1.Text="<Marquee><h1>Welcome!</h1></marquee>";

}
else
{
// cache item exists, so too bad...
Label1.Text="<Marquee><h1><font color=red>ILLEGAL LOGIN ATTEMPT!!!</font></h1></marquee>";
return;
}

}
```

However, the cache is set to Expire in 20minutes, which is the default session timeout. I had no knowledge of application cache until now. So I want to know if it's going to expire in 20mins or if it gets refreshed on postbacks like sessions do. Thank you.

Comment: Application *state* should be available at all times. See exceptions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178594(v=vs.140)#application-state-considerations).

Comment: postbacks do re-set the timeout. And in fact the session() end and session() start events will not trigger. The browser will cache the user logon - and you not see any session() events in this case. But to be clear - yes any postback re-starts the session timeout.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip.